# reusable const for various tests with mocha/chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm running a serie of tests using mocha/chai.

I try to keep those tests as simple as possible so they are easy to read. That's why I'm using a lot of it() declarations.

For each one of those tests I'm using the same const. 
Instead of re-declaring it each time I'd like to declare it just once and be done with it.

```
describe('#getLastAchievements', async function (): Promise<void> {
        it("should return an array", async function (): Promise<void> {
            const lastAch: any[] = await achievementsServiceFunctions.getLastAchievements(idAdmin, 3);
            expect(lastAch).not.to.be.equal(null);
            expect(lastAch).to.be.an('array');
        });

        it('should not be empty', async function (): Promise<void> {
            const lastAch: Object[] = await achievementsServiceFunctions.getLastAchievements(idAdmin, 3);
            expect(lastAch.length).to.be.above(0);
        });
```

I tried declaring my const in various ways but everytime the tests don't run or the conts is undefined. Here is what I tried:

-declaring it before the it()

-declaring it in a before() function

-declaring it in a anonymous function then including the it() inside this function

-declaring it outside the describe() function

Is there a way to declare this const just once to re-use it for various tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare stuff in beforeEach if they are the same for every it().

example:

```
describe('myTest', () => {
    let foo;

    beforeEach(() => {
        foo = new Foo();
    });

    it('test 1', () => {
        //do something with foo
    });

    it('test 2', () => {
        //do something with foo
    });
})
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. Do you have any idea why declaring the variable and assigning it a value before the it() functions doesn't work?

Comment: It depends on the code, you should be able to declare simple stuff (like var limit = 10), but async code can cause issues. That being said, you should'nt declare stuff this way because tests can modify objects, which will break the rest of your tests. A const object is not actually a constant and CAN change. const user = {
  name: 'foo'
}

user.name = 'bar'

console.log(user.name); //-> bar